# Adding to a dictionary based on key and value from lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary defined as:

```
letters = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 5}
```

I want to add values to this dictionary based on two lists: one which contains the keys and another which contains the values.

```
key_list = [a, c]
value_list = [2, 5]
```

This should give the output:

```
{a: 4, b: 1, c: 10}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I am new to working with the dictionary structure so I apologise if this is extremely simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the two lists and then add to the dictionary as so;

```
letters = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 5}

key_list = ['a', 'c']
value_list = [2, 5]

for k,v in zip(key_list, value_list):
    letters[k] = letters.get(k, 0) + v
```

Using the dictionary's `get()` method as above allows you to add letters that aren't already in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(key_list)):
    letters[key_list[i]] += value_list[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add or modify values from a dictionary using the key
For example:

```
letters = {'a': 2, 'b':1 , 'c': 5}

letters['a'] += 2
letters['c'] += 5

print(letters)
```

output = {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'c': 10}